# Ruby: initialize() vs class body?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, what is the difference between putting code in an `initialize()` method rather than directly in the class body? Both appear to be executed when calling `MyClass.new`.

Clearly, `initialize()` can accept parameters, but is that the only difference?

```
class MyClass
  puts 'Hello'

  def initialize(params)
    puts 'World'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try to create two instances of MyClass

```
a = MyClass.new
b = MyClass.new
```

to see the difference:

> Hello
>
> World
>
> World

Code in the class body execute only once - when ruby loads the file.  initialize() executes every time you create a new instance of your class.

Comment: Also, in _initialize_ you have the object instance to work with.

Answer (score 9):

Well, `initialize` gets called by `new`, whereas the class body gets evaluated on class definition/loading.

Additionally, try setting an instance variable in the class body or in `initialize`. You'll notice the latter will belong to the created object, whereas the first will belong to the class instance (hence the name class instance variable).

Answer (score 3):

if you write a code in  class body it will be executed when ruby load that class, the loading can be happen only once. And initialize will be executed only when you make an instance of class, and it will be executed every time when you call new to class.

now when you do MyClass.new ruby loads class MyClass it will look for class in memory if it is not then load that class, then call its new method to create instanc