# What is this property called in a ruby class

Tags: ruby, class

What is `validates` in ruby, not in rails? Is it a class variable, or some sort of code that doesn't need to be in `def initialize` method for the class `Person`?

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Comment: It's a method that takes, as arguments, `:name, presence: true`

Comment: So a call to validates method from the base class? Isn't it supposed to be within def initialize?

Comment: It validates activerecord fields. Google search "rails activerecord validations" and you'll find lots of documentation.

Comment: It's a method call. How do we know this? Because you pass arguments, and method calls are the only things in Ruby you can pass arguments to! (Well, okay, keywords, too, but the list of keywords is limited, fixed, and small, so it is trivial to just look it up and see that `validates` is not a keyword.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a **class method**. Its receiver is the class `Person`. Allowing the `self` receiver to be omitted, parentheses to be omitted, the arrow in a hash to be omitted when the key is a symbol, and braces around the hash literal to be omitted in the final-argument position make such DSL possible. If you fully write the method call in the ordinary way, it would look like:

```
Person.validates(:name, {:presence => true})
```

Comment: So is that code the same as this?

`class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.validates :name, presence: true
  end
end`

Comment: No. It is not defining a method. It is calling an already defined class method.

Comment: But then shouldn't it be within def initialize? Still learning ruby, didn't come across this style anywhere in the tutorials.

Comment: Found it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043618/ruby-initialize-vs-class-body

Answer (score 0):

Validates is rails specific.

[Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html) it is in the rails api docs

[Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2bb0abbec0e4abe843131f188129a1189b1bf714/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb#L104) it is in GitHub

You can write your own validators without rails by creating a method that runs on initialization and then throws an exception if it a criteria is not met.